# Spring security ldap baseDN

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I'm trying to configure the baseDN on my Spring ldap context source, but it keeps throwing an exception:

the config is as follows:

```
<beans:bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="${ldap_server}"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="${ldap_searchbase}"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

my ldap_searchbase has a space in it, and I've looked at the Spring code: that causes the issue:

```
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(String providerUrl) {
        Assert.hasLength(providerUrl, "An LDAP connection URL must be supplied.");

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(providerUrl);

        ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Work out rootDn from the first URL and check that the other URLs (if any) match
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String url = st.nextToken();
            String urlRootDn = LdapUtils.parseRootDnFromUrl(url);

            urls.add(url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf(urlRootDn)));

            logger.info(" URL '" + url + "', root DN is '" + urlRootDn + "'");

            if (rootDn == null) {
                rootDn = urlRootDn;
            } else if (!rootDn.equals(urlRootDn)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Root DNs must be the same when using multiple URLs");
            }
        }
```

I get the "Root DNs must be the same when using multiple URLs" error, and I notice that the String tokenizer tokens by whitespace, so it's chomping my baseDN and making it into a seperate LDAP server URL.  What gives?  What am I doing wrong here?

I get the same issue (obviously) if I configure as such:

```
<beans:bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="${ldap_server}/${ldap_searchbase}"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright - so I haven't figured out how I can provide a search base to the security context source, but by doing this:

```
<beans:bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="${ldap_server}"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

and:

```
<beans:bean id="ldapUserSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="${ldap_searchbase}"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="${ldap_auth_search_filter}"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
    </beans:bean>
```

it works.

Answer (score 4):

DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource was written in a way that it cannot handle spaces as it self.

This was first reported as a bug in [ISSUE-2264](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2264).
But as per the comments of the bug, it seems this was a known issue and solution suggest to use an escape character(i.e. `%20`)
More examples of LDAP URL can be found in : [Section-3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2255#section-3)

Therefore when you define your LDAP DNs do as below:

Real URL:

```
ldap://ldap.itd.umich.edu/o=University of Michigan,c=US
```

Corrected URL to be used for DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource Parameter:

```
ldap://ldap.itd.umich.edu/o=University%20of%20Michigan,c=US
```

Comment: is the space. Is there a possibility to scape the character such as `University\ of\ Michigan` ??